# Lighthouse GraphQL middleware not working

Tags: laravel-lighthouse

I used all possible ways to use middleware with Lighthouse! but no solution.

When I use `@middleware` directive -> I saw that it is already deprecated!

I have used `@guard` instead, it works for only `@guard(with: ["api"])`
and this guard gives me possibility to protect endpoints to be Authenticated.

I search all the internet for over 2 weeks, no solution!

I need A to Z how to implement the middleware for latest Lighthouse version and compare it with the way I do implement and see if it will work.

Comment: Hi there, have you checked out this page: https://lighthouse-php.com/5/security/authentication.html? This explains it pretty well I think, you do some setup in the `ligthouse.php` config file and then you can use `@guard` in your schema to "guard" fields/queries etc. If you are running into trouble still, tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: Hi , yes sure I have tried , but did not work

Comment: You will have to be a bit more specific on what is not working for someone to be able to try and help you out :) Explain what is not working exactly, try telling us what you are doing, and how; what is happening and what you expected to happen.